# https //127.0.0.1:111001 unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: ionic-framework

https//127.0.0.1:111001 unexpectedly closed the connection

I need to hit https//127.0.0.1:111001 for Mantra Rd service connection . but not able to hit Getting error connection closed (I am using IONIC for mobile application) The same thing is working on web with angular8.

please help...

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: You sure that you are using 111001 port? Max is 65535. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 0):

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
let url = "https://127.0.0.1:11100"

xhr.open('DEVICEINFO', url);

const params = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <PidOptions ver="1.0"> <Opts fCount="' + 5 + '" fType="' + "FMR" + '" iCount="' + 1 + '" pCount="' + 1 + '" format="' + 0 + '"   pidVer="' + 2.0 + '" timeout="' + 60000 + '" posh="UNKNOWN" env="' + 'P' + '" /> ' + 'this.DemoFinalString' + '<CustOpts><Param name="mantrakey" value="' + '' + '" /></CustOpts> </PidOptions>';
// set `Content-Type` header
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');


xhr.send(params);



xhr.onload = async () => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/xml');
  this.obj = await this.xmlToJsonfn(xml);
  this.currentdeviceInfoSubject.next(this.obj);
};


xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.log('eoor', e);
  if (e.type == 'error') {
    // alert('please download the Driver');
  
  }
};
```